# A variation of Farkas' Lemma

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be given. Show that exactly one system has a solution.

1. $\quad A x \geq 0, \quad A x \neq \mathbf{0}$
2. $\quad A^T y = 0, \quad y > \mathbf{0}$

Comment: kindly include your attempt.

Comment: Do you mean Farkas's lemma???

Comment: @MishaLavrov If the lemma is varied, so should the name, right?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh any interest in checking my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, it based on the proof [here](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6300/fall2008/Lectures/lec07.pdf):

Notice that $(2)$ is equivalent to saying that $0$ is in the interior of the conic combination of the rows of $A$. Let's call this set $Q$:

$$Q = \text{int} \,\text{cone}\{a_1, a_2,..., a_n\}$$

Assume that $(2)$ does not hold. There are three cases:

1. $0$ can be strictly separated from $Q$ by a hyperplane.
2. $0$ can be separated from $Q$ by a hyperplane, but not strictly.
3. $0$ cannot be separated, and $0$ must be in $Q$.

Case 3 is not possible, since this is a contradiction.

Case 2 is more general than case 1, so we show that for case 2:

We can separate $0$ from the set $Q$ since it is convex and $0$ is a single point. So, there exists an $\alpha$ and a $\beta$ such that:

$$\alpha^T0 \leq \beta$$

$$\alpha^Tz \geq \beta$$

for all $z \in Q$. This shows that $\alpha^Tz \leq 0$ for all $z \in Q$. For each row of $A$, $a_i$, we can choose a $z$ arbitrarily close to it. So, this implies that $A\alpha \geq 0$ so setting $x$ to $\alpha$ we have that $Ax \geq 0$.

Now to show that $Ax \neq 0$. Since $0 \not \in Q$, we have that for at least a single element $z$ of $Q$: $0 < \alpha^Tz = \alpha^T \left(\sum_i a_i \right)$ so that $\alpha^T a_i > 0$ for at least one $a_i$.

Now assume that $(2)$ does hold, so that $0 \in Q$. Then there is no separating hyperplane, meaning that for each $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\beta>0$, there is some $z \in Q$ such that $\alpha^Tz \leq \beta$. Since $\beta$ is arbitrary, we can take it arbitrarily close to $0$ so that we can always find a $z \in Q$ such that $\alpha^Tz \leq 0$. All that remains to show is that this implies that $\alpha^Ta_i \leq0$ for some $i$.

By the definition of $z$:

$$z = \sum_i \lambda_i a_i$$

for some set of $\lambda_i >0$. Then:
$$\alpha^Tz = \sum_i \lambda_i \alpha^T a_i \leq 0$$

Since all the $\lambda_i > 0$ then at least one of the $\alpha^Ta_i$ must be negative. So we are done.

Comment: if $A=I_2$, then $(2)$ doesn't hold. In that case, $\mathcal{Q}$ is the set of tuples of positive numbers. In your attempt, it is stated that there is such an $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^tz > \beta > 0$. Does it mean we have $\alpha_1z_1 + \alpha_2 z_2 > 0$ ? Besides convexity, do we need closure of $\mathcal{q}$ for your argument?

Comment: Ah that's right, I am even dealing with the interior of $Q$, so we do not always have strict separation.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. if $\mathcal{Q}$ is in the interior, then we can't conclude that $a_i \in \mathcal{Q}$ right?

Comment: But we can show choose a value in $Q$ that is arbitrarily close to $a_i$, so it shouldnt be a problem, right?

Comment: How do we ensure that $Ax \ne 0$?

Comment: Here is my idea: in my answer I only handled the case where $y$ must be identically $0$ for $(2)$ to not hold. Certainly $y$ cannot be strictly positive elementwise since then $(2)$ would hold (contradiction). So we just need to figure out the case where $y_i > 0$ for some indices but $0$ otherwise. For this case, $0 \in \text{bd}\, \text{cone}\{a_i\}$. So we do not have strict separation of $0$ from $Q$. But $a_i$ can be separated strictly for all $i$ where $y_i >0$.

Comment: I updated the answer, and thank you for all your feedback, very helpful!